# login to a session with no display server (no X) in order to use a custom display server

Tags: xorg, lightdm, session

Is it possible to login via LightDM in to a session that does not automatically start X. I have a custom.desktop in /usr/share/xsessions/

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Custom
Comment=Custom
Exec=/path/to/custom_bin
TryExec=/path/to/custom_bin
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @danzel i am running a non-X, non-Wayland compositor, and would like to start a session without them.